# javascript module using closure and a function

Tags: javascript

This code is my first attempt to create a module which gives the full name when given the nick name. but I am getting undefined in the results and don't know why. Thanks

```
let nameProper = (function nameProper (nameShort) {
  let names = {
    "fj": "Fred Johnson"
  };
  return function () {
    return names['nameShort'] || nameShort;
  };
}());

let myName = nameProper('fj');
```

Comment: `names['nameShort'] || nameShort;` why are you stringifying `nameShort`? you probably want `names[nameShort] || nameShort;`

Comment: when you use ['nameShort'] with quote, it looks for that string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const nameProper = (function () {
  const names = {
    fj: "Fred Johnson"
  };

  return function (nameShort) {
    return names[nameShort] || nameShort;
  };
})();

let myName = nameProper('fj');
```

You need to pass your argument to the inner function, not your closing function that is invoked immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
let nameProper = function(nameShort)
{
    return this.names[nameShort] || nameShort;
}
.bind
({
    names:
    {
        "fj": "Fred Johnson"
    }
});

let myName = nameProper('fj');
```